# delete dragged element after jquery drag and drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have the following jquery code

```
$( "#location1 div" ).draggable({
                appendTo: "body",
                helper: "clone"

              });

              $( "#location2" ).droppable({
                activeClass: "ui-state-default",
                hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
                accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
                drop: function( event, ui ) {
                  $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
                  $( "<li></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
                }
              })
```

This works fine but the element that was dragged is not deleted, so if I drag an element from one div to another then both divs contain that dragged element. I want to drag the element from div1 to div2 and have the element only appear in div2 (ie remove it from div1 after the drop).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could try $(ui.draggable).remove(); in your drop function.

Comment: brilliant man, @Matt